# Construct a monotonic function $f$ on $\Bbb R$ so that $f'(x)$ exists (finitely) for every $x\in \Bbb R$ but $f'$ is not a continuous function.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

This is an exercise from Rudin's Real and Complex Analysis book.

> Construct a monotonic function $f$ on $\Bbb R$ so that $f'(x)$ exists (finitely) for every $x\in \Bbb R$ but $f'$ is not a continuous function.

How can I construct such a function?

Comment: What does this question have to do with measure theory?

Comment: Discontinuous in how many points?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Maybe the function is almost an integral or something like that? I don't know. It is in a measure theory book.

Comment: @YiorgosS.Smyrlis At least one, I think

Comment: @YiorgosS.Smyrlis Well it has to be a finite amount otherwise $f^\prime$ wouldn't exist over every $x\in \mathbb R$. However one should work.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom: Maybe Rudin had some Cantor function shenanigans in mind?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Example
$$
f(x)=\left\{
\begin{array}{ccc}
2x & \text{if} & x\le 0,\\
2x+x^2+x^2\sin(1/x) & \text{if} & x> 0.
\end{array}
\right.
$$
Then 
$$
f'(x)=\left\{
\begin{array}{ccc}
2 & \text{if} & x\le 0,\\
2+2x+2x\sin(1/x)-\sin(1/x) & \text{if} & x> 0.
\end{array}
\right.
$$

Clearly $f$ is increasing and differentiable everywhere, but $f'$ is discontinuous at $x=0$.

Answer (score 2):

Start with

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}
x^2\sin(1/x) & x\neq 0\\
0 & x=0
\end{cases}$$

It is well known that

$$f'(x)=\begin{cases}
2x\sin(1/x) -\cos(1/x) & x\neq 0 \\
0 & x = 0
\end{cases}
$$
is discontinous at $x=0$. However $f'(x)$ is bounded. So let $C$ be some lower bound of $f'$. Define $g(x)=f(x)+Cx$. Then $g'(x)=f'(x)+C > 0$ everywhere and thus by the first derivative test $g$ is increasing yet $g'$ is still discontinous at $x=0$.

Comment: I would like to accept your answer too, but Yiorgos had this idea first, although your answer is more simple. Thanks man +1